# How to test code block inside observable subscription for Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular service method that uses another service for making api call. After the call success and inside of the subscription, I call some methods e.g. notifySucess, emit new value...

My question is how can I test the code block inside the subscription e.g. expect notifySucess to have been called. I put a break point inside the subscription, but the code execution does not stop there.

For testing component, I know there is 'fixture.detectChanges()' method to be applied. For service testing, are there any similar mechanism?

resource.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ResourceService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,  
  ) {}

  putData(newData: Data): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.put<Data>('/api/put-endpoint', newData);
  }
}
```

store.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StoreService {
  constructor(
    private resource: ResourceService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
  )

  saveChanges(newData: Data) {
    this.resourceServie.putData(newData).subscribe(() => {
      this.notificationService.notifySuccess('Save changes successfully');
      // do something else
  }
}
```

store.service.spec.ts

```
describe('StoreService', () => {
  let storeService: StoreService;
  let resourceService: jasmine.SpyObj<ResourceService>;
  let notificationService: jasmine.SpyObj<NotificationService>;

  notificationService = jasmine.createSpyObj('NotificationService', ['notifySuccess']);
  resourceService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ResourceService', ['putData']);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: ResourceService, useValue: resourceService },
        {
          provide: NotificationService,
          useValue: notificationService,
        },
      ],
    });
  });


  it('should saveChanges', () => {
    const newData: Data = {foo: bar};
    resourceService.putData.and.returnValue(of(newData));

    storeService.putData(newData);
    expect(resourceService.putData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newData); // PASS

    expect(notificationService.notifySuccess).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Save changes successfully); // FAIL as the code block inside the subscription does not run
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spy need to return some value for triggering subscription.
More advanced information about spy you can read [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1240/create-your-angular-unit-test-spies-automagically)
You need to use:

```
const newData: Data = {foo: bar};
resourceService = spyOn(resourceService,'putData').and.returnValue(newData);
```

instead of:

```
resourceService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ResourceService', ['putData']);
```

You also can see the similar post - [Angular - unit test for a subscribe function in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839955/angular-unit-test-for-a-subscribe-function-in-a-component)

---

Try to implement store.service.spec.ts in this way:

```
describe('StoreService', () => {
  let storeService: StoreService;
  let resourceService: ResourceService;
  let notificationService: NotificationService;

const newData: Data = {foo: bar};
resourceService = spyOn(resourceService,'putData').and.returnValue(newData);
resourceService = spyOn(notificationService,'notifySuccess').and.returnValue('Save changes successfully');

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [],
    });

 resourceService= TestBed.inject(ResourceService);
 notificationService= TestBed.inject(NotificationService);
 storeService = TestBed.inject(storeService);
  });

  it('should saveChanges', () => {
storeService.saveChanges(newData);

expect(resourceService.putData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newData); 
expect(notificationService.notifySuccess).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Save changes successfully); /
  });
})
```

Comment: The spy already returns value: `resourceService.putData.and.returnValue(of(newData));`